# Problems using HTTPSConnection with http.client

Tags: http, https, httplib, http.client

I'm new to Python and especially to web coding. I'm trying to make a program that asks for a name and a surname, and then check on Pipl if there is any result(s). My "tactic" is to directly go to the URL (containing the information) with the result, without using POST method to complete the fields of the website. I tried this:

```
import http.client
name = input("Name: ")
surname = input("Surname: ")
url = "pipl.com/search/?q=" + name + "+" + surname + "&l=&sloc=&in=5"
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url, 443)
conn.putrequest('GET', '/')
conn.endheaders()
r = conn.getresponse()
print(r.read())
```

And I'm getting this error:

> socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

I think that's because I don't only use the domain name (pipl.com), but nothing helps me, I still stuck here.

I also told myself that using POST will be maybe easier. I repeat, I'm very new to web coding (and I don't have the best English), I'm learning, so thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The best way by all means is using the PIPL code libraries. Still, if you want something that's more "quick and dirty", use the python 'requests' library (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) which can be installed with pip and gives you what you need with ease.
I took your initial code and came up with this:

```
import requests
name = input("Name: ")
surname = input("Surname: ")
url = "http://api.pipl.com/search/?first_name=" + name + "&last_name=" + surname + "&key=sample_key"
response = requests.get(url)
print (response.json())
```

The end results is the json response from the API.
Read more about the API possible responses at https://pipl.com/dev/reference/#response

Comment: Thanks for your helpfulls answers Dan ! I used the PIPL libraries and it work just fine.